# How do I convert a tuple to an Integer in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples, iterable

So i am trying to check if on one of all possible permutations I will get a form where the matrix is diagonally dominant but when trying to check for it i get an error

```
import numpy
from itertools import product
A = numpy.array([[10., -1., 2., 0.],
    [2., -1., 10., -1.],
    [-1., 11., -1., 3.],
    [0.0, 3., -1., 8.]])

def dominance(A):
    dominance=True
    n=4
    sumC=numpy.sum(numpy.absolute(A),axis=0)
    sumR=numpy.sum(numpy.absolute(A),axis=1)
    resC = [0 for i in range(n)]
    resR= [0 for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        resC[i]=sumC[i]-A[i,i]
        resR[i]=sumR[i]-A[i,i]
        if A[i,i]<resC[i] or A[i,i]<resR[i]:
            dominance=False
            break

    return dominance

def permutate(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)


if dominance(A):
    print "Es dominante"
else:
    for i in permutate(A):
        if dominance(list(i)):
            print "this way is dominant"
            print i
            break
```

this here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Prueba.py", line 37, in <module>
        if dominance(list(i)):
    File "Prueba.py", line 16, in dominance
        resC[i]=sumC[i]-A[i,i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: You don't need to "convert a tuple to an integer," you need to figure out why you're trying to use a tuple where you need an integer.

Comment: `A[i,i]` you can't index like that. Use `A[i][i]`

Comment: @hellpanderrr: You can and should with NumPy arrays, actually. The problem is that this code mixes lists and arrays without seeming to understand the differences between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `A` as a list of lists.  You get this error when you pass it to `dominance`:

```
In [87]: dominance(A)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
      8         for i in range(n):
----> 9                 resC[i]=sumC[i]-A[i,i]
     10                 resR[i]=sumR[i]-A[i,i]
     11                 if A[i,i]<resC[i] or A[i,i]<resR[i]:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

But if you first make `A` an array, it runs fine:

```
In [94]: dominance(np.array(A))
Out[94]: False
```

I won't dig into why `dominance` has problems, but it looks like `dominance` was written with numpy arrays in mind, not lists of lists.  `sumC=numpy.sum(numpy.absolute(A),axis=0)` treats `A` like an array (it works with list `A` because internally `absolute` converts it to an array).

The 2nd call to `dominance` must also get an array:

```
dominance(np.array(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this very inefficiently!

---

**If you are seeking strict diagonal dominance:**

- each row of the matrix can only have 0 or 1 strictly dominant values
- each column of the matrix can only have 0 or 1 strictly dominant values
- if any row or column has 0 strictly dominant values, there are no strictly diagonally dominant permutations of the matrix
- if every row and every column has exactly 1 strictly dominant value, then there is exactly 1 strictly diagonally dominant permuted matrix: for each row of the original matrix, the column index of the dominant item specifies the index of the row in the permuted result matrix

This results in an O(n^2) algorithm instead of O(n^2 * n!) - for a 10*10 matrix, it should be something like 3 million times faster.

---

**If you are seeking non-strict diagonal dominance:**

- each row of the matrix can only have 0, 1 or 2 dominant values
- each column of the matrix can only have 0, 1 or 2 dominant values
- if any row or column has 0 dominant values, there are no diagonally dominant permutations of the matrix
- (reduction:) if a row has exactly 1 dominant value, and that value's column contains 2 dominant values, the other dominant value in that column can be trivially disregarded (and vice-versa)
- if every row and every column has exactly 1 dominant value, then there is exactly 1 diagonally dominant permuted matrix: for each row of the original matrix, the column index of the dominant item specifies the index of the row in the permuted result matrix
- sets of rows having 2 dominant values can combine to form circuits, where each circuit has 0, 1, or 2 diagonally dominant solutions (and selecting a dominant value for one row forces the selection for all other rows in the circuit). A branch-and-prune approach can very quickly find all valid solutions.

For a matrix having t rows with 2 dominant values, this results in an O(n^2 * 2^t) algorithm instead of O(n^2 * n!) - for a 10*10 matrix, it should be between 3 thousand and 3 million times faster (depending on the number of rows having 2 dominant values).